# How do I round to 1, 1.5, 2 etc instead of 1, 2 or 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 in R?

Tags: r, rounding

I want to round numbers to the closest half or whole number. So I want to round 4.2 to 4, 4.3 to 4.5 and 4.8 to 5. I tried a few things with the round option:

```
> round(4.34,1)
[1] 4.3
> round(4.34)
[1] 4
> round(4.34,0.5)
[1] 4.3
> round(4.34,2)
[1] 4.34
```

So I only know how to increase the amount of significant numbers, but not how to do different kinds of rounding. Can that be done with the round function, or is there a different function to do that in R?

Comment: I don't know R, but can you double the number, then round it, then divide by 2?  Such as 4.34 * 2 is 8.68, round up to 9, then divide by 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the function `round_any` in package `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)

x <- 4.34

round_any(x, 3)
[1] 3

round_any(x, 1)
[1] 4

round_any(x, 0.5)
[1] 4.5

round_any(x, 0.2)
[1] 4.4
```

Answer (score 11):

This works without any extra package:

```
x <- c(4.2, 4.3, 4.8)
round(x*2)/2
#[1] 4.0 4.5 5.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know R, but I believe this would work, syntax aside:

```
y = x / 5
z = round(y, 1)
r = z * 5
```